# Accuracy score for comparison of two probability grids

Tags: probability, distributions

I would like to calculate an accuracy score for two grids. The cells of the grid have a probability of being occupied (1 = occupied, 0 = free). One grid is supposed to be the reference grid (blue) and I want to measure how similar the second grid (red) is. For easier understanding I illustrated the problem.

[image]

Am I on the right track with the Kullback-Leibler-Divergence? Or is there something better?

I already stated that [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/114677/occupancy-octree-metrics-kullback-leibler) yesterday but in retrospective I think I might have formulated it too specificly.

Comment: Note that these are not probability distributions, but really 16 separate (presumably independent?) distributions per grid.  This question has abstracted so much from your original one that although answers may be suggestive, it is not clear how applicable they would be. For instance, the answers to your question about octrees should depend on how those octrees were constructed (the answers ought to be very different for fixed octrees and adapted octrees, for instances).

Comment: The octree was constructed by successively transfering scans (point clouds) into the octree. Currently, I use all voxels at maximum depth (they have the same resolution) for calculating precision and recall rates. Of course in this calculation the nodes are either free or occupied, which leads to my question. @whuber Do you have a suggestion?